# Kotlin data class unexpected result

Tags: kotlin

I have dataclass with val field

```
@Parcelize
data class MemberCard(
        val PartnerMembershipId: Int,
        override var MembershipNumber: String? = null,
        override var Name: String? = null,
        var MemberImgUrl: String? = null,
        val TextColorHex: String? = null,
        override var ExpirationDate: Date? = null,
        override var Issuer: String,
        var Notifications: kotlin.Int? = null,
        override var BarcodeType: kotlin.String? = null,
        override var Barcode: kotlin.String? = null,
        val IsPartnerCard: Boolean,
        val Status : String
) : BaseCard {
    val isPending = true//Status=="Pending"
}
```

for some unknown reason in runtime I have isPending = false

is it some Kotlin initialization magic?

Comment: Please show where you are checking this

Comment: I set a breakpoint and see it in the debugger, but also app behaves like isPending is always false

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you have a problem with @Parcelize. Quoting:

"@Parcelize requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. Android Extensions will issue a warning on each property with a backing field declared in the class body. Also, @Parcelize can't be applied if some of the primary constructor parameters are not properties."

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

and

"Properties with initializers declared in the class body are also difficult to deserialize correctly: we'd have to generate an alternative constructor that does not execute initializers (including init blocks) at all and only uses the serialized data, but this has all the issues that java.io.Serializable has wrt "magic" object creation."

Source:
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md part "Simple case: completely automatic Parcelable"

So im almost 100% sure that what you need to do is to correct Parcelable interface implementation.

Comment: hmm, but it is not a property it is constant and must be initialized after the constructor call

Comment: It is not constant. It is javish 'final' property. To create constants you should wrap it with companion object.